# FileSystemResource as ResponseBody in spring rest controller gives ClassCastException

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have defined a controller which serves local content like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = PATH_CONTENT, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> getContent(
    @PathVariable(URI_PATH_PARAM_CONTAINER_UID) String containerUid,
    @PathVariable(URI_PATH_PARAM_DOC_UID) String docUid) {
    ...
}
```

In the client side:
I am adding ResourceHttpMessageConverter to RestTemplate messageConverters.
When I finally make the following call:

```
ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> response = getMyRestClient()
        .getContent(url, null, FileSystemResource.class);
FileSystemResourcecontent = response.getBody();
```

This produces a `ClassCastException` saying it cant cast `ByteArrayResource` to `FileSystemResource`.

I can do some modification to my code to return a `Resource` instead of `FileSystemResource` and things will work. But I am really wondering why is this exception? I also don't want to take the path of writing to `HttpServletResponse` directly as I want to use Spring's `HttpMessageConverter` framework.

Comment: I get the same exception for UrlResource too. Is it a bug in Spring's ResourceHttpMessageConverter code? –
protected Resource readInternal(Class<? extends Resource> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
                   throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException { 

            byte[] body = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(inputMessage.getBody());

            return new ByteArrayResource(body);  
        }

Comment: It seems to have multiple issues which prevents one from returning any concrete Resource type as a response from service because there is a ClassCastException while receiving as Spring converts the resource to a concrete ByteArrayResource. To avoid this I receive as a Resource but that’s a bad limitation.
Secondly, this method converts the whole response to byte array which can cause OOME for big response (e.g. big binary content).